# Count of Specific words in Multiple text files

Tags: python

I have a multiple text files and I need to find and cound specific words in those files and write them in a csv file. Column A contains the txt file names and in the header the words and for each file name its count. With this code I am getting all the words and need to filter out exact words

for example the output should be like the image file I uploaded

header = ['Abuse', 'Accommodating', 'Accommodation', 'Accountability']

```
import csv
folderpaths = 'C:/Users/haris/Downloads/PDF/'
counter = Counter()
filepaths = glob(os.path.join(folderpaths,'*.txt'))
for file in filepaths:
    with open(file) as f:
        words = re.findall(r'\w+', f.read().lower())
        counter = counter + Counter(words)
    print(counter)
f = open('C:/Users/haris/Downloads/PDF/firstcsv.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(f)
for row in counter.items():
    writer.writerow(row)
```

[image]

[Files uploaded to google drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1u7uJ4zohEHqoBvmZMQU68HpDk9HYT6l5?usp=sharing)

Comment: You could show us what your text files look like because it is hard to visualize what you are trying to do at the moment.

Comment: upload sample contents of a text file here

Comment: Hello uploaded the files

Comment: @HarisTrading thanks for the files. I have submitted an answer. Do take a look and let me know if that is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: As per your new request, I have added the "total_words" column. The code has been updated.

[image]

---

Below is a code that works. Just change the "folderpath" variable to the path of the folder with the text files, and change the "target_file" variable to where you want the output csv file to be created.

Sample csv output:

[image]

Code:

```
from collections import Counter
import glob
import os
import re

header = ['annual', 'investment', 'statement', 'range' , 'deposit' , 'supercalifragilisticexpialidocious']
folderpath = r'C:\Users\USERname4\Desktop\myfolder'
target_file = r'C:\Users\USERname4\Desktop\mycsv.csv'

queueWAP = []
def writeAndPrint(fileObject,toBeWAP,opCode=0):
    global queueWAP
    if (opCode == 0):
        fileObject.write(toBeWAP)
        print(toBeWAP)
    if (opCode == 1):
        queueWAP.append(toBeWAP)
    if (opCode == 2):
        for temp4 in range(len(queueWAP)):
            fileObject.write(queueWAP[temp4])
            print(queueWAP[temp4])
        queueWAP = []
mycsvfile = open(target_file, 'w')
writeAndPrint(mycsvfile,"file_name,total_words")
for temp1 in header:
    writeAndPrint(mycsvfile,","+temp1)
writeAndPrint(mycsvfile,"\n")
filepaths = glob.glob(folderpath + r"\*.txt")
for file in filepaths:
    with open(file) as f:
        writeAndPrint(mycsvfile,file.split("\\")[-1])
        counter = Counter()
        words = re.findall(r'\w+', f.read().lower())
        counter = counter + Counter(words)
        for temp2 in header:
            temp3 = False
            temp5 = 0
            for myword in counter.items():
                temp5 = temp5 + 1
                if myword[0] == temp2:
                    writeAndPrint(mycsvfile,","+str(myword[1]),1)
                    temp3 = True
            if temp3 == False:
                writeAndPrint(mycsvfile,","+"0",1)
        writeAndPrint(mycsvfile,","+str(temp5))
        writeAndPrint(mycsvfile,"",2)
        writeAndPrint(mycsvfile,"\n")
mycsvfile.close()
```

Comment: can I add another field in the last column which will count all the words in the text file?

Comment: @HarisTrading I have updated the code to add the "total_words" as you wanted. Please check.

Comment: Hello @Joshua - the count of words are not appearing correctly, I need to have the total number of words in the text file and they are showing quite less when I do a word count.

`Totalwords = (len(query))
with open(target_file, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    data = [["resultwords", Totalwords], resultwords ]
    writer.writerows(data)
print(Totalwords)`     


wrote another code to find that but stuck, cannot seem to glob my way,

Comment: @HarisTrading I used your generator object to get the total words. I didn't use my own function haha. So, if it is wrong, that means your generator object is wrong. Hold on, let me check your generator object and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I am stopping myself from commenting but here I am , did you had a chance to look at it @joshua

Comment: after removal of "+" it stopeed counting the header words, and the count is still not accurate, I also noticed its counting numbers as words.
here is another program but tried but still not giving an accurate result.
`folderpath = r'C:/PDF/txt'
target_file = r'C://txt/mycsv.csv'
filepaths  = [os.path.join(folderpath, name) for name in os.listdir(folderpath)]
all_files = []
for path in filepaths:
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
       file = f.read().lower()
    #print(file)
    words = file.split()
    all_files.append(file)
    print(len(words))`

Comment: @HarisTrading Counting numbers as words is normal. If you type a report in microsoft word and click on "word count" button, the result will include the numbers too inside the word count. The regex you used in your generator (\w+) also includes numbers inside the word count. That is an industry standard. If you don't want numbers, try to use "[a-zA-Z]+" instead of "\w+". Let me know if it works.  So, it should look like this: `re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+', f.read().lower())`

Answer (score 0):

Using 'Counter' seems to be the right choice here, but I think you are using it wrong.

Here is a possible solution that may work for you:

```
words = ['Abuse', 'Accommodating', 'Accommodation', 'Accountability']

rows = []
for file in filepaths:
  with open(file, 'r') as f:
    words_in_file = [word for line in f for word in line.split()]
  # this will count all the words in the file (not optimal)
  wordcounts = Counter(words_in_file)
  # interested only in specific words
  counts = list(map(lambda x: wordcounts[x], words))
  # insert first column (filenam)
  counts.insert(0, file)
  # append it to the rest of the rows
  rows.append(counts)

f = open('C:/Users/haris/Downloads/PDF/firstcsv.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(f)
for row in rows:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Hello @JuanR i am getting no output in the csv file, its blank

Comment: Sorry, I copied your code but did not change a variable name. The last for should be `for row in rows` instead of `for row in counter.items()`. It's fixed now.